# Criteria API (Specification JPA) Join

Tags: java, sql, criteria, specifications, criteria-api

Here is my current models

```
@Entity
public class A {

@Id
private Long id;

String name;

...

@Entity
public class B {

@Id
private Long id;

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
private A a;

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "c_id")
private C c;

...

@Entity
public class C {

@Id
private Long id;

private String status;
```

I want a List of class A where status of class C is "ACTIVE" **using Criteria API with explicit JOIN** as bellow example with **IN**

```
Subquery<B> subQB = query.subquery(B.class);
Root<B> rootB = subQB.from(B.class);
subQB.select(rootB.get("c").get("id"))
                      .where(builder.equal(rootB.get("c").get("status"), "ACTIVE"));        
predicates.add(root.get("id").in(subQB)); // root is class A
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: By *"using only specification"* do you mean *"using Criteria API"*?

Comment: @Andreas Yes. I'll fix this.

Comment: So, you want to re-write the existing query? Also, does `A` have a relationship with `B`?

Comment: @Smutje Yes, I want rewrite. No, only B have relationship with A and C.

Answer (score 0):

Without an actual running database shouldn't it be something similar to

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

// Because the result is "A"
CriteriaQuery<A> q = cb.createQuery(A.class);

// Start from B
Root<B> bRoot = q.from(B.class);

// Path from B to A, as local variable to increase readability
Path<A> aPath = bRoot.get("a");

// Path from B to C and to C's status, as local variable to increase readability
Path<C> cPath = bRoot.get("c");
Path<String> cStatusPath = cPath.get("status");

// SELECT A FROM B WHERE B.C.Status = "ACTIVE"
q.select(aPath)
  .where(cb.equal(cStatusPath, "ACTIVE"));
```

Edit:

An explicit join should be looking very similar to the first solution, so

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

// Because the result is "A"
CriteriaQuery<A> q = cb.createQuery(A.class);

// Start from B
Root<B> bRoot = q.from(B.class);

// Path from B to A, as local variable to increase readability
Path<A> aPath = bRoot.get("a");

// Join from B to C and to C's status, as local variable to increase readability
Join<B, C> cJoin = bRoot.join("c");
Path<String> cStatusPath = cJoin.get("status");

// SELECT A FROM B WHERE B.C.Status = "ACTIVE"
q.select(aPath)
  .where(cb.equal(cStatusPath, "ACTIVE"));
```

Comment: Any idea using explicit Join? I’m using Spring Jpa Specification